# FancyBox not showing the image once clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm using the FancyBox plugin to get a nice gallery viewer for my images. I have the images showing up on my index page, but when I click on them the fancybox displays with the correct dimensions of the desired image, but without the image. Not even a broken image path symbol, just a blank as if its display is simply turned off.
My html is as follows,

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="unveil1.jpg" title="Title">
    <img src="img/loading.gif" data-src="unveil1.jpg"/>
</a> 
<a class="fancybox" rel="fancybox-thumb" href="img/unveil2.jpg" title="Title">
    <img src="img/loading.gif" data-src="img/unveil2.jpg"/>
 </a>
```

While my js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers : {
        title   : {
            type: 'outside'
        }

    }
 });

 $("img").unveil(200, function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        this.style.opacity = 1;
    });
 });
});
```

You can ignore the unveil plugin, all it does is lazy load images and I've tried taking it out and I still have the same problem.
I had trouble if JSFiddles external libraries, so here is the [link to my dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103257004/Unveil/index.html)

Thank you guys!

Comment: Try moving your main.js at the end of head section

Comment: @jtorrescr To no avail, Thanks for the suggestion though, I know that has worked for me in the past, I'm going to swap some things around and see if that will produce anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. 
I was setting a transition using unveil to start at opacity 0 and transition from there. This was setting my image when clicked on to not transition and remain at opacity 0!